# SQL/PHP Silent Refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Is there any way to silently refresh the page containing data from my SQL Database?
I want to make it so that it will change the value of my paragraph (choice1) whenever the info in the database is changed

Everything works and on first load it outputs the same value as is the database, but when i change the value in the database it doesn't change on the value on the page without me refreshing

can anyone help me?

```
<html>
<p id="choice1"></p>
<script>
function refresh(){
   setInterval(function () {
      document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML =<?php
             $connect=mysql_connect("****","**","***"); 
             mysql_select_db("enloecsc");
             $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE number=1");
             $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query);
             echo $query2['q1'];
             ?>> ; 
   }, 1000);
}
</script>

<html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: PHP is server side.  As soon as that last malformed html tag is output its work is done.  You need to use ajax for this task.

Comment: As dan says, you are looking for Ajax

Comment: can you refer me to a link on how to use ajax for this task?

Comment: jQuery is a library with an Ajax implementation that is very convenient. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont mind refreshing the whole page, you can try using meta refresh tag in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;http://www.example.com/index.php" />
```

if you want to use a div, you will have to use ajax. A good way to do it is through jquery:

```
//javascript code, assumes jquery is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() { $('#myDiv').load('contentToLoad.php');}, 5000);  
});
```

contentToLoad.php would have the content as a php script (or anything you want, including html)